# How to connect to the database using sqlite in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm creating a program using C# and sqlite.

I need to connect my database, which is located on private server.
How can I do it?

I already wrote some code to connect to my database on local system, but it's not what I want.

And code, which I already wrote, can: connect to database and write some strings in DB and in the end - close the connection.

This is my code:

```
 const string databaseName = @"C:\Users\ADmin\Desktop\selfie\db.db";
 SQLiteConnection connection =
 new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", databaseName));
 connection.Open();
 SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO 'qasu' ('question', 'answer', 'solution', 'uri') VALUES ('" + questionn + "','" + answwer + "','solution','uri');", connection);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 connection.Close();
```

Comment: Btw, your command is vulnerable to SQL injection. Read about [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid it

Comment: It's not important for my program. I will used my program personally 3-4 times at year.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the database file on a fileshare on the server and make sure your client machine has access rights.

```
const string databaseName = @"\\server\share\db.db";
```

Note however that it is not recommended to access an SQL Lite database from a network share, you might get locking issues according to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using phpmyadmin and I have no idea where is DB is located. 
Can I write, if I can found physical located this db on my private server, this code in my program:                                                         
const string databaseName = @"\\77.136.1.1\lib\phpmyadmin\save\db.db";